# What actually is model size scaling and how do i globally apply to every model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science-model

I read this article on the EfficientNet paper and have seen a lot of this kind of scaling. For example, there's **Tiny-YOLO**, **YOLO** (the base),.. Some model like **SVTR**, people did scale it to Tiny, Small, Large version, etc.

So how do i do this, what to do with the height, width and resolution and are there any methods that help me doing this ?.

Let say i have a model A. and i want to scale it to these:

**Tiny A**

**Small A**

**A** (default, base version)

**Large A**

**Very Large A**

I know it not always good to apply this but sometime i need inference speed, sometime i need accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

From the paper and as I understand it:

Increasing width is about increasing the number of convolutional filters.

Increasing depth is increasing the number of layers.

Increasing resolution is about using larger (i.e more detailed) images as the input

I dont know of any methods directly that do the scaling like you want but many pre-built models have different sizes (efficient net has b0, b1, b2 etc.) you could experiment with.

Their paper also describes:

"In this paper, we propose a new compound scaling method,
which use a compound coefficient φ to uniformly scales
network width, depth, and resolution in a principled way:

[image]

where α, β, γ are constants that can be determined by a
**small grid search**."